# How to display ajax get request data to html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/get/posts',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#title').html(data.title);
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr, error);
  }
});
```

I successfully fetch the data and now I want to display it. I tried to be simple by adding a div with and id of "title", then loading the response data into the div dynamically.But that data is not showing.

```html
<div id = "title">
    <span ></span>
</div>
```

My goal is to display the response data inside a card. I can perfectly do this with blade syntax but i just want to learn more about basic javascript, so that when I start using frameworks there will be fewer headaches.

Here's how i fetch the data :

```
public function get_ajax_post(){
        $posts = Post::all();
        return json_encode($posts);
}
```

heres the console.log

```
1: {…}
​​
category: "python"
​​
content: "<p>asd asd asd</p>"
​​
created_at: "2020-05-26T16:43:34.000000Z"
​​
featured_image: "null"
​​
id: 2
​​
slug: "asdas-dasd"
​​
title: "asdas dasd"
​​
updated_at: "2020-05-26T16:43:34.000000Z"

....... and so on
```

Thanks for the help. I googled a lot on how to display get request in ajax dynamically, but all I saw are post request, and I've already done that.

My goal now is to fetch data and display it dynamically on my view. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You seem to have everything working. Is all you're asking is how to insert the response data into a card?

Comment: Yes . But the data that should be in the span tag is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think your question is, "I get a string from an ajax call, and now I want to insert that string into a `div` using jQuery."

If that's your question, then you're doing it correctly.

If you want your HTML to show up inside that `<span>` tag though, you just need to change your jQuery selector to: `$('#title span').html(data.title);`

Comment: You could also try using the `.append()` method like this: `$('#title span').append(data.title)`. You also might want to try just console logging the specific property you want to insert to make sure that it's getting accessed correctly like this: `console.log(data.title)`

Comment: Thanks ill try that one

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, the goal is to take the `title` property from the response data:

```js
const data = {
  category: "python",
  content: "<p>asd asd asd</p>",
  created_at: "2020-05-26T16:43:34.000000Z",
  featured_image: "null",
  id: 2,
  slug: "asdas-dasd",
  title: "asdas dasd",
  updated_at: "2020-05-26T16:43:34.000000Z"
}
```

And display it inside this `span` tag:

```html
<div id = "title">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

This vanilla JavaScript will accomplish that task:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('title');
const span = div.firstElementChild;
span.innerHTML = data.title;
```

```js
const data = {
  category: "python",
  content: "<p>asd asd asd</p>",
  created_at: "2020-05-26T16:43:34.000000Z",
  featured_image: "null",
  id: 2,
  slug: "asdas-dasd",
  title: "asdas dasd",
  updated_at: "2020-05-26T16:43:34.000000Z"
}

const addTitle = () => {
  const div = document.getElementById('title');
  const span = div.firstElementChild;
  span.innerHTML = data.title;
}
```

```css
#title {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

span {
  outline: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addTitle()">Add Title</button>
<div id="title">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If we're doing vanilla js, you could also probably make it simpler by doing `document.querySelector('#title span').innerHTML = data.title`

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather That's true, thanks. I chose the more verbose method to make it a bit more understandable.

Comment: Yeah I get that, I just like to give multiple ways of doing things :)